# Transferring a file to two destinations efficiently

Tags: curl

At present I am creating a backup file and using `curl` to send it to a remote host, using:

```
tar -cvzf - ./folder | curl -u user:pwd ftp://example.com/folder/backup.tar.gz --ftp-create-dirs -T -
```

I also want to send the *same file* to a *different destination* on the *same host* (actually, in the same folder but with one having a datestamp in the filename and the other not).

At present I'm just running the above (including `tar`) twice, specifying different destinations in each.  This is clearly OK but sub-optimal.

Is it possible to "fork" the output from `tar` and send it to two different `curl` commands?

Or, more efficiently perhaps in terms of bandwidth to the remote host, transfer the file to the host once and then copy it in situ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tee` to clone stdout to file and then run second `curl` after the first has finished. Or you can just change `tar` parameters to save backup to local file and then run two `curl` processes to transfer it to remote host. Both solutions are not very good in terms of bandwidth, speed and local disk space.

I think the best solution is to transfer file once and then copy it in situ. You can use `ssh` with [public key authentication](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key/) instead of `curl` to avoid exposing user password and easy file cloning at remote host:

```
tar -cvzf - ./folder | ssh -i ~user/.ssh/id_dsa user@example.com 'tee /folder/backup_datestamp.tar.gz | dd of=/folder/backup.tar.gz'
```

You can change private key location at local host if you don't have local user *user* (and don't forget to copy public key to remote host for successful authentication). You can also use `dd of=file1 ; cp file1 file2` instead of using `tee` in a command at remote host.

Comment: Thanks... set me in the right direction (i.e. using ssh).  But the host doesn't have `dd` and I don't have control over that, so I ended up using something like `tar -cvzf - ./folder | ssh user@xx.yyy.zz.aaa "cat - | tee xyz.tar.gz > abc.tar.gz"`